# What anti-cheating measures does pokemon have?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

What anti-cheating protections exist in Pokemon 6th gen?

I am interested because I am trying to decide whether I want to use the online trade features. If I am going to use those features, I want to know that I (or the game itself) will be able to identify Pokemon that were hacked.

Comment: We generally do not help with anything that involves cheating or hacking here. There are plenty of other resources on the internet for that

Comment: @ThePickleTickler We don't help with people who are trying to break a game's TOS. This question is asked in good faith about identifying and avoiding other people who do break the TOS, which I don't see a problem with at all.

Comment: @StrixVaria Okay, my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game has a very basic hack check for services that require the internet, such as battling, the GTS, and trading over wifi. This will only check for data that can actually exist in the games. For example, a Weedle can never normally learn Hyper Beam, but if you try to trade one that has it, the game will say there is a problem and will not allow it to be traded.

That being said, the hack check isn't very reliable and sometimes lets things through that would otherwise be impossible to obtain, such as an [aegislash in a dream ball](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/69612399).

If a pokemon has been hacked but looks identical to a legitimate pokemon, the game will not be able to detect this.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds about right. It checks the best it can for "impossibilities". Pokemon below the level they can possibly appear as (such as a lvl1 Zekrom), stats outside of the possible range for that Pokemon, impossible movesets. But, it really isn't perfect. You mentioned the ball limitations... I still remember about a year ago, the incident with all the [foul-named Jirachis](http://kotaku.com/players-are-trying-to-clean-up-pokemons-hacked-trading-1672459613). If a Pokemon is hacked but does not break any of these rules, it is basically undetectable, and passes through the validations.